# Pairwise comparison of elements in a list python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Given a list below:

```
snplist = [[1786, 0.0126525], [2463, 0.0126525], [2907, 0.0126525], [3068, 0.0126525], [3086, 0.0126525], [3398, 0.0126525], [5468,0.012654], [5531,0.0127005], [5564,0.0127005], [5580,0.0127005]]
```

I want to do a pairwise comparison of the second element in each sublist of the list, i.e. compare to see `0.0126525` from `[1786, 0.0126525]` is equal to `0.0126525` from `[2463, 0.0126525]` and so forth, if so, print the output as indicated in the code.

Using for loop, I achieve the result:

```
for index, item in enumerate(snplist, 0):
    if index < len(snplist)-1:
        if snplist[index][1] == snplist[index+1][1]:
            print snplist[index][0], snplist[index+1][0], snplist[index][1]
```

When doing pairwise comparisons of the elements of a loop using list index, I always get into the error of `'index out of range'` because of the last element. I solve this problem by adding a condition

```
if index < len(snplist)-1:
```

I don't think this is the best way of doing this. I was wondering if there are more elaborate ways of doing pairwise comparisons of list elements in python?

EDIT: I had not thought about the level of tolerance when comparing floats. I would consider two floats with `0.001` difference as being equal.

Comment: You are comparing floats. Define "equal". What's the tolerance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `zip` the `snplist` with the same list excluding the first element, and do the comparison, like this

```
for l1, l2 in zip(snplist, snplist[1:]):
    if l1[1] == l2[1]:
      print l1[0], l2[0], l1[1]
```

Since you are comparing floating point numbers, I would recommend using [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) function from Python 3.5, like this

```
def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
```

As you want to have 0.001 tolerance, you can do the comparison like this

```
if is_close(l1[1], l2[1], 0.001):
```

Comment: hmm, OP is using Python2.7, how do you get `math.is_close` imported?

Comment: @timgeb It is a simple two-liner. I hope he can copy paste and use it :-)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you use `izip` for this to create a generator of item-neighbor pairs. Leaving the problem of comparing floating points aside, the code would look like this:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> lst = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,4], [7,8], [9,10], [11, 10]]
>>> for item, next in izip(lst, lst[1:]):
...     if item[1] == next[1]:
...         print item[0], next[0], item[1]
... 
3 5 4
9 11 10
```

Remember to specify a tolerance when comparing floats, do *not* compare them with == !

You could define an `almost_equal` function for this, for example:

```
def almost_equal(x, y, tolerance):
    return abs(x-y) < tolerance
```

Then in the code above, use `almost_equal(item[1], next[1], tolerance)` instead of the comparison with ==.